# Need to save dynamically generated CSV from URL

Tags: php, csv

Basically I have a supplier who can offer me a CSV file of prices and stock via there website from a secure area.

I have sorted my script to login OK. Next step is to call a url

http://******.co.uk/trade/account/pricelist.aspx

When accessed in a web browser this dynamically generates a CSV and automatically downloads to my PC.

So far I have this;

`file_put_contents($csv_file, fopen($qm_url, 'r'));`

all it does is save the source code of the webpage and not the dynamic content generated.

How can I make a PHP script save the generated file to a folder on my server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either look at the curl extension in PHP, or use an external program like curl or wget.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://**.co.uk/trade/account/pricelist.aspx');
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.csv', $file);
```

**Note**: `allow_url_fopen` will need to be enabled in php.ini in order for `file_get_contents` to work with a URL.

Comment: Hi @AbraCadaver, This is what I have already tried;

`file_put_contents($csv_file, fopen($qm_url, 'r'));` 

all it does is save the source code of the webpage and not the dynamic content generated.

Comment: And... Would be good to add that to the question as well as how it didn't work.